# What Does Forged Alliance Have Less?

Tags: supreme-commander

Time ago I played the original Supreme Commander game (at my friend's home) and it was cool, then other games passed by and now I felt nostalgic about it, so I came back and see if it could be a good idea to buy it, finding out that an "expansion" is out: Forged Alliance.

Forged Alliance is a stand alone, so you don't need the original game to play, which sounds good. It adds a new race, a new campaign, like 100 new units, which sound very good.

They still sell both games as different games, so I wonder: why should someone buy the base game instead of Forged Alliance? What does the latter has less?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do not have a key for the original Supreme Commander you will be limited to only playing the new faction the Seraphim in Online Play.

The campaign for Forged Alliance is significantly shorter than the original game. Forged Alliance contains a total of six missions (for which you can choose to play as UEF, Aion or Cybran). The original game contains eighteen missions in total (six for each faction).

Comment: So are you saying that Forged Alliance has ONLY the new race and the new campaign? What about skirmish matches against IA in local? Will I be able to play only the new race?

Comment: I've just started up my copy (I've own the original, but it isn't installed and I don't remember ever entering my key), and I can select any race in the skirmish menu. I've also updated my answer regarding the campign.

Comment: Thanks a lot... now I'm wondering... buying both for 14,99 EUR... or just Forged Alliance for 9,99 EUR... :P (It all depends on how much I'll want to play online, after all...)

Comment: @Frhay no, it does not ONLY have the new race + campaign, it has a rework to the engine, a lot of bugfixes, a whole new modernized and more spacious UI and a lot of balance tweaks as well as new units & mechanics for all the races + one new experimentals for each race which in each case is my facorite for that race. And of course vs other players and AI you get to play seraphim.

Comment: @Frhay you don't need to buy both i'd say forged alliance alone is best.

Comment: @tatsu thanks for the insight but after 6 years I've already bouth both, played a lot both and actually decided that FA is better, especially with FAF. :)